# xampp server is not working after windows upgrade , i want backup of my old project data in new window 11

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

Recently I upgraded my pc from windows 10 to windows 11by using a bootable pen drive. before that, I take a backup of XAMPP files by copying the whole XAMPP folder from the c drive to another drive.
after the installation of Windows 11, I installed the XAMPP server and replaced the C:\xampp\htdocs folder with the old htdocs folder. and also replace ibdata 1 file located in the C:\xampp\mysql\data folder.
but when I tried to reach my project file it asks for a WordPress installation again. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jObdn.png)and when I proceeded with installation it appears that
WordPress database error: [Table 'wp_users' already exists]
I also tried by replacing the whole xampp folder but that also did not work. Please help because there are very important [projects in xampp.old folder

Answer (score 0):

I've just found your post Sachchidanand Dubey.

Did you Export the databases as well as copying the files?

It may be too late now but suggest trying the same procedure used for Updating XAMPP which is normally a six step process:

Export your databases.

Backup your website files.

Uninstall or rename the old version of XAMPP.

Install the new version of XAMPP.

Adjust PHP settings.

Restore your website files and databases.

Also, when Exporting try using the Drop table option so that when Importing, the table is dropped then re-created. Doing so usually liminates the Table already exists error.

You can also use the XAMPP Shell CLI to export databases.

Further help, Google is your friend.